# Subfolder non-www redirect

Tags: apache, htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect

Is there a way to redirect a sub folder to `no-www`?

What I use is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but this only redirects the `www.example.com` to `example.com`.

I would like to redirect:

`www.example.com/home/` to `example.com/home/`

`www.example.com/home/whatever` URL to `example.com/home/whatever` URL.

I have tried this:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This does not work, either. I can't really figure it out. Any help appreciated!

## ANSWER

I figured it out and I will post it for others to see, if having the same issue.

In the sub folder directory's *.htaccess* used the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.example\.com)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/subfoldername/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: this code is not correct `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.example\.com)?$ RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/subfoldername/$1 [R=301,L]` this redirect internal URL to homepage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following *.htaccess* code for stealth sub-folder redirection:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.example\.com)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/subfoldername/$1 [R=301,L]
```